# md-input placeholder is not working with ngModel value binding

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular2, recently added Material to the project.
when trying to convert my inputs, I encountered an issue with the binding.
I'm binding the input with ngModel, and when doing that, the placeholder stays on the value until hovering over the input, then the placeholder moves up.
any idea?

"@angular/common": "^2.4.2",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",

```
<md-input-container>
    <input md-input placeholder="{{ title | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="value">
</md-input-container>
```

[image]

Comment: please reproduce here : https://plnkr.co/edit/FBcTUXg5qQP0MLE1BgiT?p=preview

Comment: @micronyks the value comes as @Input(), not sure how to do it in plnkr.

Comment: No Problem you can put value without @input as of now. forget about child component or something. just reproduce it. My problem is just with translate api so asking you to  reproduce it.

Comment: @micronyks here is the reproduce:https://plnkr.co/edit/SvLMGXEQ85nu19CJ6pf2?p=preview

Comment: That's happening because of onPush strategy. https://plnkr.co/edit/yXCMq1yWBEe45IHfuGtD?p=preview any specific reason to use it?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that also. we are using this strategy since we have regular updates on the page. do you have any solution without removing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was fixed at material2.0.0-beta.10

Answer (score 0):

According to testing, I found the solution to bind the string with translation to the placeholder of input (Angular materail 2)

```
 <md-input-container class="input-container">
      <input mdInput
             name="username"
             ngModel
             placeholder="{{('Username'|translate)+('Or'|translate)+('Email'|translate) }}"
             align="end"
             required="required">
 </md-input-container>
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand the difference between you solution to my.

Comment: ok I got your point. because you use the onPush, so it is the problem. Have you tried the latest version of beta.2? I just use official plunker to make a demo with onPush strategy and the display is ok. see http://plnkr.co/edit/S7w9rcqAE4NU4Lapeu6D?p=preview

Comment: we have some differences in our code, take a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/x8RW54MZMQz6gjAe3mPR?p=preview , i have a component which has a selector, and a @Input

Comment: updated link with Angular4 and material beta3: https://plnkr.co/edit/FncXapgEEdqJU7R3kU8X?p=preview